# Disable scrolling out of map or on another

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The google map api has a very weird behavior. The user can scroll out of the map at the top and bottom. On left and right there are endless copes of the map on the left and right.
[[image: 1]]

This looks exactly the same on all maps of the documentation. Can this be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict how far a user can zoom out which may solve your problem:

```
 // This is the minimum zoom level that we'll allow
 var minZoomLevel = 1;

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     zoom: minZoomLevel,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });

 // Limit the zoom level
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
     if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
 });
```

Using this will stop the user from zooming so far they see multiple maps

http://jsfiddle.net/9d4jy4ye/1107/

Comment: Thank you now the user can not zoom but still simply move out of the map.

Comment: what do you mean move out of the map? Do you have an example i can use? i.e. JSfiddle

Comment: Just drag the map down.